# "Cannot resolve scoped service 'IDbContext' from root provider" exception in AWS only after update .NET 3.1 to .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, .net-6.0

I have a Web API originally created with .NET Core 3.1. This Web API is hosted in AWS.

This Web API was updated to .NET 6.0 in development environment.

The code has not been changed. Only whats is needed to update the .NET version.

Running the API in local environment everything works correctly, however, when we deploy to AWS, we start getting an exception on every request.

The exception is `"Cannot resolve scoped service 'IDbContext' from root provider"`, this exception is launched in Invoke method that adds an Entity in `HttpContext.Items`.

This Invoke method has parameters HttpContext and IDbContext. In other Invoke methods, I remove IDbContext and it did not throw any more exceptions, but in this specific Invoke method I need the IDbContext to add a Entity in `HttpContext.Items`.

I don't know what to do, I've tried to change the method in several ways, but it always throws the same exception when it's running in the cloud.

We've already updated the other APIs and we didn't have this problem, they ran normally.

The Invoke method is:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IDbContext dbContext)
{
    var identifier = GetContextIdentifier(httpContext);

    if (identifier != null)
    {
        string cacheKey = _key + identifier;

        var institution = _cache.Get(cacheKey) as Institution;

        if (institution == null)
        {
            institution = await dbContext.Institutions.Where(x => x.Code == identifier).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (institution != null)
            {
                var cacheEntryOptions = GetCacheEntryOptions();

                _cache.Set(cacheKey, institution, cacheEntryOptions);
            }
        }

        if (institution != null)
        {
            httpContext.Items[institution.GetType().Name] = institution;
        }
    }
}
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebAPI.Domain/WebAPI.Domain.csproj", "WebAPI.Domain/"]
COPY ["WebAPI.Application/WebAPI.Application.csproj", "WebAPI.Application/"]
COPY ["WebAPI.Infrastructure/WebAPI.Infrastructure.csproj", "WebAPI.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["WebAPI.Persistence/WebAPI.Persistence.csproj", "WebAPI.Persistence/"]
COPY ["WebAPI.WebApp/WebAPI.WebApp.csproj", "WebAPI.WebApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebAPI.WebApp/WebAPI.WebApp.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebAPI.WebApp"
RUN dotnet build "WebAPI.WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebAPI.WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebAPI.WebApp.dll"]
```

My Startup:

```
namespace WebAPI.WebApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Environment = environment;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

        readonly string DevelopmentOrigins = "_developmentOrigins";

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMultitenancy<Tenant, TenantResolver>();

            services.AddDbContext<IDbContext, DbContext>(opt => opt.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseWrite")));
            services.AddDbContext<ITenantDbContext, TenantDbContext>(opt => opt.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseWrite")));

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                    builder.WithOrigins("https://*.abc.education", "https://abc.education").SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();
                });

                options.AddPolicy(DevelopmentOrigins, builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                });
            });

            services.Configure<AppSettings>((settings) =>
            {
                Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(settings);
            });

            services.Configure<AwsOptions>((settings) =>
            {
                Configuration.GetSection("Aws").Bind(settings);
            });

            services.AddSingleton<AuthFilter>();
            services.AddScoped<BasicAuthorizationFilter>();

            services
                .AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson();

            services.AddMvc()
                .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<IDbContext>());

            services.AddApplication();
            services.AddInfrastructure();
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());

            services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3>();
            services.AddAWSService<IAmazonDynamoDB>();

            services.AddTransient<IDynamoDBContext, DynamoDBContext>(ctx =>
            {
                var client = ctx.GetService<IAmazonDynamoDB>();
                var options = ctx.GetService<IOptions<AwsOptions>>();
                return new DynamoDBContext(client, new DynamoDBContextConfig { TableNamePrefix = options.Value.DynamoDBTableNamePrefix, Conversion = DynamoDBEntryConversion.V2 });
            });

            services.AddScoped<AwsSqsService>();
            services.AddScoped<AwsCloudFrontService>();

            services.AddScoped<FileService>();

            services
               .AddHttpClient<IApplicationService, ApplicationService>()
               .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = false });
            services
               .AddHttpClient<IInstitutionService, InstitutionService>()
               .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = false });

            services.AddScoped<IUsernameResolver, UsernameResolver>();
            services.AddScoped<IRoleResolver, RoleResolver>();
            services.AddScoped<IInstitutionResolver, InstitutionResolver>();
            services.AddScoped<IDatabaseResolver, DatabaseResolver>();

            services.AddSingleton(Environment.ContentRootFileProvider);

            services
                .AddHealthChecks()
                .AddNpgSql(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DatabaseWrite"]);
        }

        private static void HandleWithoutTenant(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseDatabase();
        }
        
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseHealthChecks("/v1/webapi/health");

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCustomExceptionHandler();

            app.UseRouting();

            if (env.IsEnvironment("Local")) app.UseCors(DevelopmentOrigins);
            else app.UseCors();

            app.UseAuthorization();




            app.UseWhen(context => ShouldUseTenant(context),
                               HandleWithoutTenant);

            app.UseWhen(
                context => !(context.Request.Method.Equals(HttpMethod.Options.Method, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) && !(ShouldUseTenant(context)),
                appBuilder =>
                {
                    appBuilder.UseMultitenancy<Tenant>();
                    appBuilder.UseDatabase();
                    appBuilder.UseInstitutionResolution();
                }
            );

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't simply update to .NET 6.  There are other steps you need to follow.  For example .NET 6 does not use the Statup class unless told to do so.  The services should be registered in the Program.cs file.  I think you might want to do some reading or at the very least look at a new project template by simply creating .NET 6 project is VS.

Comment: Using Startup and the Generic Host used by the ASP.NET Core 3.1 and 5.0 templates is fully supported in .NET 6.0. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#apps-migrating-to-60-dont-need-to-use-the-new-minimal-hosting-model)

The steps used to upgrade are the ones in the documentation on (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-60)

And the API runs perfectly in local environment after update. All APIs were updated in the same way and only this one has this problem.